# Google Sign-In With PHP But Not Using Library

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Following, and modifying, some of the instructions from [this Google help article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_4_add_the_sign-in_button_to_your_page), I've gotten JavaScript to return a code something like this (this one from Google's example):

```
{"code":"4/yU4cQZTMnnMtetyFcIWNItG32eKxxxgXXX-Z4yyJJJo.4qHskT-UtugceFc0ZRONyF4z7U4UmAI"}
```

Which I can then send to my PHP server. However, I'm at a loss for how to process it on the server-side, without using Google's libraries; I'd prefer to just make an HTTPS request from the server to Google with the code to get the data back, instead of importing their entire API. Is this possible and how would I go about doing that?

In the end, the main data I want to get out is the email address and Google ID with which I can then go on to create an account for the user in my own database.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is step 1 you have the authorization code.

Next step is to exchange it for an access token This should be sent as a http Post

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>   code={Authorization code}&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&grant_type=authorization_code

The server should return with something like this

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

Any request you send to the api just add &Access_token={the access token}

To get a new one after that one has expired you do another HTTP POST to get a new one using the refresh token from above

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 
>   client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token

server should respond with

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Note: I have only done this with server applications haven't actually tested it with a web application.  It should work just make sure your redirect uri is set correctly.

Let me know if you have any problems.  Code ripped from my [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) tutorial.